# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

The app is crashing on android 8.

When I try to open any activity from mainActivity, then press back to the main activity and try to open any other activity is crashing the app

it say that the app could not stop the main activity!

**this is the log**

```
2018-10-23 12:19:33.963 20358-20358/global.medicount.healthpass.dev E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: global.medicount.healthpass.dev, PID: 20358
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {global.medicount.healthpass.dev/global.medicount.healthpass.ui.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4038)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1625)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added
    at android.view.View.removeFrameMetricsListener(View.java:6252)
    at android.view.Window.removeOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener(Window.java:889)
    at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:436)
    at android.support.v4.app.FrameMetricsAggregator.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:246)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zze.onActivityStopped(Unknown Source:60)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStopped(Application.java:234)
    at android.app.Activity.onStop(Activity.java:1862)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:636)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:184)
    at global.medicount.healthpass.ui.base.BaseActivity.onStop(BaseActivity.java:388)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1376)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:7205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4035)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap24(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1625) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
```

**dependencies:**

```
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
```

I have test this issue on old android version (6) and the issue is not happening. and the app working very well. 
I have seen some solutions to downgrade the firebase-pref, but that did not solve my issue. and I have no any idea what I have to do.

Comment: did you try to downgrade both the google services and the firebase-pref ?

Comment: @OussemaAroua, I have did a downgrade as the following
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:15.2.0'
and still have the issue

Comment: Please add the code and indicate the line at which this error occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is the solution to handle my issue to make my project compile and run successfully.

**gradle project**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.0'
    versionCode = 18
    versionName = '3.6.0'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
    ....
}
```

**And here it is the AppGradle dependences**

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2"
```

In addition, I has got an issue in the Async tasks, so it says that the Async can be executed once time, so the solution was

```
uploadUserIdProofTask.cancel(true);
uploadUserIdProofTask = new UploadUserIdProof();
uploadUserIdProofTask.execute(objects);
```

These lines helped me, I do not know what is the relation between this and the log, but it's working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` from `AndroidManifest.xml` under `application` tag.

This resolved my problem without downgrading any of the libs.